Any finite dimensional functional vector space is closed under point-wise convergence (reference needed)
I need a reference for the fact that every finite dimensional real function space is closed under point-wise convergence. I'm pretty sure it is true (here is my proof). However, it is clearly an elementary fact that must be well known (if true), and I'd like to have a simple reference for it.
My (hopefully correct) proof is the following. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional vector space of functions on some space $X$. Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$ be a basis. I can show by induction (for brevity I am not going to do it here, but I also believe it is well known) that there is a set of $m$ points $\{x_1\dots x_m\}\subseteq X$ such that the vectors $v_i = (f_i(x_1),\dots, f_i(x_m))$ are independent (so they are a basis for $\mathbb R^m$).
Now, I consider a sequence $(g_t)\subseteq F$ that is point-wise convergent to some $g$. Then, I can write $g_t = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_{t,i}f_i$ for some coefficients $\lambda_{t,i}$. Now, define $w_t =(g_t(x_1)\dots g_t(x_m)) = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_{t,i}v_i$. The point-wise convergence of $(g_t)$ implies that $(w_t)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}^m$ to some $w$. Since $v_1\dots v_m$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, we can write $w = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i v_i$, and so we have that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\lambda_{t} = \alpha$ in $\mathbb R^m$.
Now let $h = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_if_i\in F$. We show that $h$ is the point-wise limit of $(g_t)$. Indeed, fix any $x\in X$. We have that $$|g_t(x)-h(x)|\leq\sum_{i=1}^m|\lambda_{t,i}-\alpha_i||f_i(x)|\leq\|\lambda_t-\alpha\|_1\max_{i=1\dots m}|f_i(x)|\to 0\,.$$ Since this is true for every $x$, $g_t\to h$ point-wise. The unicity of the point-wise limit implies that $g=h$, and so we conclude.
